# SQL Connection variable not in the current context

Tags: asp.net

I am a beginner in.NEt and having difficulty using the sql connection in a radio button index changed eventhandler that i defined on the page_load.

Below is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Controls
{
    public partial class Report_Selection : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GridView1.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged);
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBSW9079;Initial Catalog=Underwriting;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))

            {
              SqlCommand cmd;
               SqlDataReader sdr;

               if (!IsPostBack)
               {
                   cmd = new SqlCommand("select Categoryid,CategoryTitle  from Report_Category", cnn);
                   cnn.Open();
                   sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                   SelectCategorydlist1.DataSource = sdr;
                   SelectCategorydlist1.DataTextField = "CategoryTitle";
                   SelectCategorydlist1.DataValueField = "categoryid";
                   SelectCategorydlist1.DataBind();
                   cnn.Close();

               }
               else
               {
                   //It's a Post back
                   //make the grid visible and fill it

                   GridView1.Visible = true;
                   RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "1";
                   cmd = new SqlCommand("Select rptdesc,rptdesctext,categoryid from report_description " + "where categoryid != 99999"
                       + "and categoryid = " + Convert.ToInt32(SelectCategorydlist1.SelectedValue).ToString(), cnn);
                   cnn.Open();
                   sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                   GridView1.DataSource = sdr;
                   GridView1.DataBind();

                   sdr.Close();





                   {


                   }

               }






                }

            }

        void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            SqlCommand cmd1;
            SqlDataReader sdr1;
            if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex.Equals(1))
            {
                RadioButtonList1.ClearSelection();
                cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select rptdesc,rptdesctext,categoryid from report_description "
                       + "and categoryid = " + Convert.ToInt32(SelectCategorydlist1.SelectedValue).ToString(), cnn);
                cnn.Open();
                sdr1= cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataSource = sdr1;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                sdr1.Close();
            }

        }







        }
    }
```

In the above code when i use the cnn sequel connection in the event handler i get an small r

Comment: Btw, why do you have functionality in page_load? You should databind your controls from page_load only `if(!IsPostback)`. The rest should be done in the appropriate event-handlers. So why do you make the grid visible and databind it on postback? What caused that postback? This event should be handled to call a method that databinds the grid and switches visibility.

Comment: So when the page gets loaded the dropdown gets populated and when there is a change in the drop down value the page posts back and retreives the data into the grid control. Iam a newbie and trying out things at this stage to have an understanding on how this works.

Comment: Then handle the `DropDownList`'s [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event and populate the grid there.

Comment: When Iam trying to populate the grid in the dropdwonlist selected index changed event it is giving me an error on the SQL connection(The error is the sql connection does not exist in the context)how do i use the sql connection i defined in the page_load everywhere on the page or how do i use the connection string i defined in my web.config everywhere in the page

Comment: Yes, since you have declared it in page_load. Don't do the databinding stuff in page_load at all. Instead transfer that code into appropriate methods (f.e. BindGridView, BindDropDown,BindData(to bundle previous methods)). Then you can  call these methods when you need from wherever you need. That's called encapsulation which makes code safer, more readable, maintanable and reusable. So create the conection and other objects in these methods.

Comment: ignore my previous comments.I found a way searching in google.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your query in `RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged` appears to be incorrect.  There's an `and` without a `where`:

```
Select rptdesc,rptdesctext,categoryid from report_description
and categoryid = ...
^^^ should be WHERE
```